# GXT 3.0.1 Multiple Store and Loader for 1 Chart

Tags: java, gxt, http-proxy

The problem here is that I need to have only one Chart (for exemple Line Chart) with multiple Series. Data comes from different WebServices so how it is possible to load in the store of one chart, more than only one loader ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Chart reads items from a single store. With multiple stores, the order of items might not make sense.

Instead, consider loading all of your items into a single store. If you are trying to achieve different lines for different sets of items, the first set of items can return a null value for the second line, and the second set of items can return a null value for the first set of items.

If instead the problem is that you want two different HttpProxies to feed into the same store, dont use the normal store binding classes to wire the loaders to the store, but make your own that only adds new items without clearing out the old ones (i.e. call store.addAll instead of store.replaceAll).

Adding more details about what you are trying to do will make it easier to answer your question.